# Why does my count route in NodeJS not working?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
const express = require('express')
const Task = require('../models/task-model')
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')

const router = new express.Router()

router.post('/tasks', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const task = new Task({
        ...req.body,
        owner: req.user._id
    })
    try {
        await task.save()
        res.status(201).send(task)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }
})

router.get('/tasks/count', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const count = await Task.countDocuments({})
        if (!count) {
            res.send(404).send()
        }
        res.send(count)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
})
module.exports = router
```

- Every route except **count** is working.
- I have tried **count()** function, but it is **deprecated**.
- Now I am using **countDocuments({})** but it gives **500** response.
- I have tried **estimatedDocumentCount()** but **same** response.

Comment: How can we replicate the issue? How do you make the request? What does `Task.countDocuments` do? Is `auth` relevant for this example?

Comment: I dont't get whats the issue is with 500. Maybe its the actual Document Count. Have you tried running the command in mongo shell?